# full page details coming on ajax success function result- codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm just working on how ajax actually works on codeigniter. And,problem what i'm facing is : In ajaxex.php,there is one div namely 'ShowMember', where i want to display member details after selecting 'member id' from the dropdown. Data is not coming ok ,But what coming is full 'ajaxex.php page' in 'ShowMember' div after selecting value from dropdown. Please help. I just started using codeigniter. Thanks.

### ajaxex.php (view)

```
<div>
  <select class='form-control EmployeeIDs' name='EmployeeID' id='EmployeeIdenity'>
                <option value="">Select Employee</option>
                <?
                foreach($results as $row) 
                {
                $MemberID=$row->MemberID;
                $EmployeeID=$row->EmployeeID;
                ?>
                <option value="<?echo $MemberID;?>"><?echo $EmployeeID;?></option>
                <?}?>
            </select>
</div>

<div class='ShowMember'></div>
```

### mystyle.js

```
$('#EmployeeIdenity').change(function(){
    var MemberID = $('#EmployeeIdenity').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"welcome/ajaxFindMemberDetails",
        type:"GET",
        data:{MemberID:MemberID},
        success:function(result){
            $('.ShowMember').html(result);
    }});
});
```

### Controller

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();

                $this->load->model('news_model');
        $this->load->library('session'); // Start Session
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        }
       public function ajaxFindMemberDetails()
       {
        $data1['MemberDetailsResult'] = $this->news_model->memberDetails($MemberID);
        $this->load->view('admin/ajaxMemberDetailsPage',$data1);
       }
}
```

### ajaxMemberDetailsPage.php (VIEW)

```
<?
foreach($MemberDetailsResult as $rowMemDetails) 
{
    echo $MemID=$rowMemDetails->MemberID;
?>

<?}?>
```

### Model

```
class News_model extends CI_Model 
{
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->load->database();
        }
        public function memberDetails($MemberID)
       {
            $this->db->where('MemberID', $MemberID);
            $query = $this->db->get('member');
            $MemberDetailsResult = $query->result();
            return $MemberDetailsResult;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you removed `index.php` from your url?? if not than you might need to try this: `index.php/welcome/ajaxFindMemberDetails` and try to make this in quotes like this: `{'MemberID':MemberID}`

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola 

var MemberID = $("#EmployeeIdenity option:selected").val();
 $.ajax({
  url:"<?php echo site_url();?>('welcome/ajaxFindMemberDetails')",
  type:"GET",
  data:{'MemberID':MemberID},
  dataType : 'html',
  success:function(result){
   $('.ShowMember').html(result);
 }});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Ajax code was not able to find the correct path. So, I tried this and it worked.So, i would like to share my changes. It may help someone. Thank you @Saty, @Arnas, @Indrasinh For detecting my error. It means a lot.

### **header.php**

```
I have to set Baseurl here in head section of header.
<script>
  var BASEURL = 'http://localhost/Project/index.php/';
</script>
```

### **AjaxEx.php**

No Changes. As in question

### **Controller**

```
public function ajaxFindMemberDetails()
    {
        $MemberID= ($this->input->get('MemberID') != '' ? $this->input->get('MemberID') : 0);
        $data1['MemberDetailsResult'] = $this->news_model->memberDetails($MemberID);
        $this->load->view('admin/ajaxMemberDetailsPage',$data1);
    }
```

### **Model**

No Changes, As in question.

### **AjaxCode.js**

```
$('#EmployeeIdenity').change(function(){

    var MemberID = $("#EmployeeIdenity option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:BASEURL+"welcome/ajaxFindMemberDetails",
        type:"GET",
        data:{'MemberID':MemberID,'MemType':'Hello'},
        success:function(result){
            $('.ShowMember').html(result);  
    }});
});
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You are you getting `MemberID` in your controller.

```
public function ajaxFindMemberDetails()
       {
        $MemberID=$this->input->get('MemberID');// get MemberID
        $data1['MemberDetailsResult'] = $this->news_model->memberDetails($MemberID);
        $this->load->view('admin/ajaxMemberDetailsPage',$data1);
       }
```

And php tag in your view `ajaxMemberDetailsPage.php`

```
<?php
foreach ($MemberDetailsResult as $rowMemDetails) {
    echo $MemID = $rowMemDetails->MemberID;

}?>
```

Comment: Hey, Saty. I did this, but same result man. Whole page coming on that div. And,data is also not coming. I know you will help me. I saw you solving lot of questions.

Comment: use this to get value of selected select bon value `$("#EmployeeIdenity option:selected").val();`

Comment: No Saty. :( Still Full Page with no data coming on that div. :( :(

Comment: okk check your browser console and see the value of `MemberID` and check url is correct or not!!

Comment: Hey Saty. MemberID value coming on alert. 
It still same. 
var MemberID = $("#EmployeeIdenity option:selected").val();
 $.ajax({
  url:"<?php echo site_url();?>('welcome/ajaxFindMemberDetails')",
  type:"GET",
  data:{'MemberID':MemberID},
  dataType : 'html',
  success:function(result){
   $('.ShowMember').html(result);
 }});

Comment: check updated answer and remove `dataType : 'html',`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88376/discussion-between-danish-enam-and-saty).